# Override maxWait in tomcat 9

Tags: tomcat, tomcat9

I have a tomcat server and under tomcatFolder/conf/server.xml
I got this tag Resource

```
<Resource name="jdbc/TestDB"
      auth="Container"
      type="javax.sql.DataSource"
      factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
      testWhileIdle="true"
      testOnBorrow="true"
      testOnReturn="false"
      validationQuery="SELECT 1"
      validationInterval="30000"
      timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
      maxActive="100"
      minIdle="10"
      maxWait="10000"
      initialSize="10"
      removeAbandonedTimeout="60"
      removeAbandoned="true"
      logAbandoned="true"
      minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
      jmxEnabled="true"
      jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;
        org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
      username="root"
      password="password"
      driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
      url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mysql"/>
```

How can I override the maxWait value in setenv.sh or in catalina.sh run command ??

Comment: You can't. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have no acces to modify files

Comment: Can you explain why you can add a `setenv.sh` file and even modify `catalina.sh`, but you can not modify `server.xml`? You can always use `startup.sh -config /path/to/server.xml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how to /override/, but you can define a value in `setenv.sh` and use it in a configuration file.  For example:

```
    # setenv.sh
    JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Djdbc.maxWait=5000"
```

```
    <!-- server.xml or context.xml -->
    <Resource name=...
        ...
        maxWait="${jdbc.maxWait}"
        ...
```

UPDATE:

Tomcat releases 9.0.34 and 8.5.54 add support for default values when using ${...} property replacement in configuration files.  For 9.0.34 and 8.5.54 the separator is a colon character.  e.g.

```
maxWait="${jdbc.maxWait:10000}"
```

For 9.0.35 and 8.5.55 the separator was changed to be `:-`.  e.g.

```
maxWait="${jdbc.maxWait:-10000}"
```

(Thanks to the comments by Piotr P. Karwasz)

Comment: You can also use `${jdbc.maxWait:-10000}`: if the property `jdbc.maxWait` is not defined, the default value `10000` will be used.

Comment: Piotr, I found that your suggestion only worked without the dash "-" character.  e.g. only this works:  ${jdbc.maxWait:10000}.  Everything after then colon ":" character is included in the default value!

Comment: Apparently the separator changed from `:` to `:-` in version [8.5.55](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_8.5.55_(markt)) and [9.0.35](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_9.0.35_(markt)).

Comment: Good find Piotr!